# Multiplicities in Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, multiplicity

I have a small problem with data modelling in EA. I'm making a foreign key relationship between tables by using an 'Association' connector. Then, I specify the FK relationship and it ends up with such an effect : http://tinyurl.com/npdkoda

My question is how to change the multiplicity 'icons' to standard number based ones like '1...n' and others that you can see here http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/images/datamodeldiagram.png ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I got it - the connector notation was wrong. I had to choose properties for diagram, go to Connectors and switch Connector Notation to UML 2.1.